# Filter hash with JsonPath

Tags: ruby, hash, jsonpath

I need to find a certain hash element where one of the keys is equal to a certain value. I've tried many ways and can't seem to figure it out with `jsonpath` gem.

Need to get `tire` tag where `grip == 'bad'`

```
require "jsonpath"

hash = {
    :id => 1,
    :cars => [
        {:id => 1, :tire => {:grip => "good", :color => "black"}},
        {:id => 2, :tire => {:grip => "bad", :color => "red"}},
        {:id => 3, :tire => {:grip => "good", :color => "green"}}
    ]
}

puts JsonPath.on(hash, "$..tire[?(@['grip'] == 'bad')]").inspect
```

No results.

Comment: What is `tire` tag? What is `grip`? You have `:grip` in your "Hash" and `'grip'` in your "My code"; is it related in some way to any of these? What is `THE_HASH`?

Comment: The `tire` tag is one of the keys in the hash above. `'grip'` and `:grip` don't make a difference with `jsonpath`. `THE_HASH` is the hash that I posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[?()]` filter only works for arrays (or at least for either arrays or hashes, not both at the same time). In order for it to work, I had to enclose the `:tire` hash in an array.

Original:

```
:tire => {:grip => "good", :color => "black"}
```

New:

```
:tire => [{:grip => "good", :color => "black"}]
```

That's a "fix" that works for me. It would be better if someone fixed the `jsonpath` gem to make it work for both arrays and hashes (of the same type and at the same time).

Comment: That would be great if it could work for both Arrays and Hashes.  Do you know of anything that will convert each element of JSON into an Array if it is not already?

Answer (score -1):

In JsonPath.on first argument must be json, not hash.
I can't do it over ruby, it is not fully correct solution. But may be this help you.

```
require 'jsonpath'
require 'json'

hash = {
    :id => 1,
    :cars => [
        {:id => 1, :tire => {:grip => "good", :color => "black"}},
        {:id => 2, :tire => {:grip => "bad", :color => "red"}},
        {:id => 3, :tire => {:grip => "good", :color => "green"}}
    ]
}

json = hash.to_json
obj = JsonPath.new( "$..tire")[json]
result = obj.inject(Array.new){|res, x| res << x if x["grip"]=='bad'; res }

p result # [{"grip"=>"bad", "color"=>"red"}]
```

Comment: Did you try this with the `jsonpath` gem? I edited my question, the grip values are actually strings.

Comment: Did you try your second solution? Please test before posting answers.

Comment: No, it is not solution, unfortunately. I don't know, how write correct JsonPath. Sorry.

Comment: I posted the code in the question. You can experiment with that code.

Comment: I update my code (added hash and fix print). Now this code return array with needed "tire".

Comment: This solution works but 1. It's basically a hack for JsonPath and 2. It won't work if a `car` had more than one tire. For example: `:tire => [{:grip => "good"}, {:grip => "bad"}]`. I need it to catch both scenarios.

Comment: I'd say not a valid solution. Hash can't simply be converted to JSON. Many reasons: 1) ruby hash can have complex structures as key, like another hash; 2) values may be closures (like lambdas) 3) hashes may have cycles.

Comment: The first argument to JsonPath.on() can be a hash, but the hash keys cannot be symbols, they must be strings.  If you stringify_keys it will work.  Internally JsonPath is using a Hash/Array object, and if you pass it an Hash/Array instead of a String that bypasses the JSON decoding that it does:  https://github.com/joshbuddy/jsonpath/blob/16cfe87827b060fb77c0ad938aeaab520fa3744b/lib/jsonpath.rb#L102-L104